# error when using pip to install mujoco library

Tags: python, pip

Hi I get an error when I pip install a library called `mujoco-py`. However I am unable to identify how to resolve this from the error message below:

```
~$ pip3 install -U --user 'mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1'
Collecting mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/8c/64e0630b3d450244feef0688d90eab2448631e40ba6bdbd90a70b84898e7/mujoco-py-1.50.1.68.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: Cython>=0.27.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1) (0.29.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cffi>=1.10 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: glfw>=1.4.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: imageio>=2.1.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1) (2.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: lockfile>=0.12.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1) (0.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycparser in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.10->mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1) (2.19)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from imageio>=2.1.2->mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1) (5.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: mujoco-py
  Building wheel for mujoco-py (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-49u4_yeg --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Removing old mujoco_py cext /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/cymj_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder_37.so
  Compiling /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.pyx because it changed.
  [1/1] Cythonizing /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.pyx
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:99:4: 'mjtDisableBit' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:114:4: 'mjtEnableBit' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:121:4: 'mjtJoint' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:127:4: 'mjtGeom' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:149:4: 'mjtCamLight' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:157:4: 'mjtTexture' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:163:4: 'mjtIntegrator' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:168:4: 'mjtCollision' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:174:4: 'mjtCone' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:179:4: 'mjtJacobian' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:185:4: 'mjtSolver' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:191:4: 'mjtImp' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:198:4: 'mjtRef' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:203:4: 'mjtEq' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:211:4: 'mjtWrap' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:220:4: 'mjtTrn' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:230:4: 'mjtDyn' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:237:4: 'mjtGain' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:242:4: 'mjtBias' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:248:4: 'mjtObj' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:274:4: 'mjtConstraint' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:285:4: 'mjtConstraintState' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:294:4: 'mjtSensor' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:338:4: 'mjtStage' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:345:4: 'mjtDataType' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:99:4: 'mjtDisableBit' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:114:4: 'mjtEnableBit' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:121:4: 'mjtJoint' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:127:4: 'mjtGeom' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:149:4: 'mjtCamLight' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:157:4: 'mjtTexture' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:163:4: 'mjtIntegrator' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:168:4: 'mjtCollision' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:174:4: 'mjtCone' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:179:4: 'mjtJacobian' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:185:4: 'mjtSolver' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:191:4: 'mjtImp' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:198:4: 'mjtRef' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:203:4: 'mjtEq' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:211:4: 'mjtWrap' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:220:4: 'mjtTrn' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:230:4: 'mjtDyn' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:237:4: 'mjtGain' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:242:4: 'mjtBias' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:248:4: 'mjtObj' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:274:4: 'mjtConstraint' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:285:4: 'mjtConstraintState' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:294:4: 'mjtSensor' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:338:4: 'mjtStage' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:345:4: 'mjtDataType' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:75:4: 'mjtNum' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:77:10: 'mjPI' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:78:10: 'mjMAXVAL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:79:10: 'mjMINMU' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:80:10: 'mjMINIMP' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:81:10: 'mjMAXIMP' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:82:10: 'mjMAXCONPAIR' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:83:10: 'mjMAXVFS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:84:10: 'mjMAXVFSNAME' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:87:10: 'mjNEQDATA' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:88:10: 'mjNDYN' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:89:10: 'mjNGAIN' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:90:10: 'mjNBIAS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:91:10: 'mjNREF' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:92:10: 'mjNIMP' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:93:10: 'mjNSOLVER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:96:4: 'mjtByte' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:100:8: 'mjDSBL_CONSTRAINT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:101:8: 'mjDSBL_EQUALITY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:102:8: 'mjDSBL_FRICTIONLOSS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:103:8: 'mjDSBL_LIMIT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:104:8: 'mjDSBL_CONTACT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:105:8: 'mjDSBL_PASSIVE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:106:8: 'mjDSBL_GRAVITY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:107:8: 'mjDSBL_CLAMPCTRL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:108:8: 'mjDSBL_WARMSTART' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:109:8: 'mjDSBL_FILTERPARENT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:110:8: 'mjDSBL_ACTUATION' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:111:8: 'mjDSBL_REFSAFE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:112:10: 'mjNDISABLE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:115:8: 'mjENBL_OVERRIDE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:116:8: 'mjENBL_ENERGY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:117:8: 'mjENBL_FWDINV' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:118:8: 'mjENBL_SENSORNOISE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:119:10: 'mjNENABLE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:122:8: 'mjJNT_FREE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:123:8: 'mjJNT_BALL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:124:8: 'mjJNT_SLIDE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:125:8: 'mjJNT_HINGE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:129:8: 'mjGEOM_PLANE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:130:8: 'mjGEOM_HFIELD' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:131:8: 'mjGEOM_SPHERE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:132:8: 'mjGEOM_CAPSULE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:133:8: 'mjGEOM_ELLIPSOID' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:134:8: 'mjGEOM_CYLINDER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:135:8: 'mjGEOM_BOX' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:136:8: 'mjGEOM_MESH' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:138:8: 'mjNGEOMTYPES' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:141:8: 'mjGEOM_ARROW' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:142:8: 'mjGEOM_ARROW1' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:143:8: 'mjGEOM_ARROW2' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:144:8: 'mjGEOM_LABEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:146:8: 'mjGEOM_NONE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:150:8: 'mjCAMLIGHT_FIXED' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:151:8: 'mjCAMLIGHT_TRACK' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:152:8: 'mjCAMLIGHT_TRACKCOM' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:153:8: 'mjCAMLIGHT_TARGETBODY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:154:8: 'mjCAMLIGHT_TARGETBODYCOM' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:158:8: 'mjTEXTURE_2D' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:159:8: 'mjTEXTURE_CUBE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:160:8: 'mjTEXTURE_SKYBOX' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:164:8: 'mjINT_EULER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:165:8: 'mjINT_RK4' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:169:8: 'mjCOL_ALL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:170:8: 'mjCOL_PAIR' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:171:8: 'mjCOL_DYNAMIC' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:175:8: 'mjCONE_PYRAMIDAL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:176:8: 'mjCONE_ELLIPTIC' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:180:8: 'mjJAC_DENSE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:181:8: 'mjJAC_SPARSE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:182:8: 'mjJAC_AUTO' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:186:8: 'mjSOL_PGS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:187:8: 'mjSOL_CG' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:188:8: 'mjSOL_NEWTON' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:192:8: 'mjIMP_CONSTANT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:193:8: 'mjIMP_SIGMOID' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:194:8: 'mjIMP_LINEAR' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:195:8: 'mjIMP_USER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:199:8: 'mjREF_SPRING' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:200:8: 'mjREF_USER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:204:8: 'mjEQ_CONNECT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:205:8: 'mjEQ_WELD' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:206:8: 'mjEQ_JOINT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:207:8: 'mjEQ_TENDON' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:208:8: 'mjEQ_DISTANCE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:212:8: 'mjWRAP_NONE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:213:8: 'mjWRAP_JOINT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:214:8: 'mjWRAP_PULLEY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:215:8: 'mjWRAP_SITE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:216:8: 'mjWRAP_SPHERE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:217:8: 'mjWRAP_CYLINDER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:221:8: 'mjTRN_JOINT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:222:8: 'mjTRN_JOINTINPARENT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:223:8: 'mjTRN_SLIDERCRANK' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:224:8: 'mjTRN_TENDON' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:225:8: 'mjTRN_SITE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:227:8: 'mjTRN_UNDEFINED' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:231:8: 'mjDYN_NONE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:232:8: 'mjDYN_INTEGRATOR' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:233:8: 'mjDYN_FILTER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:234:8: 'mjDYN_USER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:238:8: 'mjGAIN_FIXED' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:239:8: 'mjGAIN_USER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:243:8: 'mjBIAS_NONE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:244:8: 'mjBIAS_AFFINE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:245:8: 'mjBIAS_USER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:249:8: 'mjOBJ_UNKNOWN' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:250:8: 'mjOBJ_BODY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:251:8: 'mjOBJ_XBODY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:252:8: 'mjOBJ_JOINT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:253:8: 'mjOBJ_DOF' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:254:8: 'mjOBJ_GEOM' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:255:8: 'mjOBJ_SITE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:256:8: 'mjOBJ_CAMERA' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:257:8: 'mjOBJ_LIGHT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:258:8: 'mjOBJ_MESH' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:259:8: 'mjOBJ_HFIELD' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:260:8: 'mjOBJ_TEXTURE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:261:8: 'mjOBJ_MATERIAL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:262:8: 'mjOBJ_PAIR' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:263:8: 'mjOBJ_EXCLUDE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:264:8: 'mjOBJ_EQUALITY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:265:8: 'mjOBJ_TENDON' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:266:8: 'mjOBJ_ACTUATOR' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:267:8: 'mjOBJ_SENSOR' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:268:8: 'mjOBJ_NUMERIC' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:269:8: 'mjOBJ_TEXT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:270:8: 'mjOBJ_TUPLE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:271:8: 'mjOBJ_KEY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:275:8: 'mjCNSTR_EQUALITY' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:276:8: 'mjCNSTR_FRICTION_DOF' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:277:8: 'mjCNSTR_FRICTION_TENDON' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:278:8: 'mjCNSTR_LIMIT_JOINT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:279:8: 'mjCNSTR_LIMIT_TENDON' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:280:8: 'mjCNSTR_CONTACT_FRICTIONLESS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:281:8: 'mjCNSTR_CONTACT_PYRAMIDAL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:282:8: 'mjCNSTR_CONTACT_ELLIPTIC' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:286:8: 'mjCNSTRSTATE_SATISFIED' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:287:8: 'mjCNSTRSTATE_QUADRATIC' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:288:8: 'mjCNSTRSTATE_LINEARNEG' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:289:8: 'mjCNSTRSTATE_LINEARPOS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:290:8: 'mjCNSTRSTATE_CONE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:296:8: 'mjSENS_TOUCH' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:297:8: 'mjSENS_ACCELEROMETER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:298:8: 'mjSENS_VELOCIMETER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:299:8: 'mjSENS_GYRO' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:300:8: 'mjSENS_FORCE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:301:8: 'mjSENS_TORQUE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:302:8: 'mjSENS_MAGNETOMETER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:303:8: 'mjSENS_RANGEFINDER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:306:8: 'mjSENS_JOINTPOS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:307:8: 'mjSENS_JOINTVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:308:8: 'mjSENS_TENDONPOS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:309:8: 'mjSENS_TENDONVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:310:8: 'mjSENS_ACTUATORPOS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:311:8: 'mjSENS_ACTUATORVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:306:8: 'mjSENS_JOINTPOS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:307:8: 'mjSENS_JOINTVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:308:8: 'mjSENS_TENDONPOS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:309:8: 'mjSENS_TENDONVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:310:8: 'mjSENS_ACTUATORPOS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:311:8: 'mjSENS_ACTUATORVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:312:8: 'mjSENS_ACTUATORFRC' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:315:8: 'mjSENS_BALLQUAT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:316:8: 'mjSENS_BALLANGVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:319:8: 'mjSENS_FRAMEPOS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:320:8: 'mjSENS_FRAMEQUAT' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:321:8: 'mjSENS_FRAMEXAXIS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:322:8: 'mjSENS_FRAMEYAXIS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:323:8: 'mjSENS_FRAMEZAXIS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:324:8: 'mjSENS_FRAMELINVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:325:8: 'mjSENS_FRAMEANGVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:326:8: 'mjSENS_FRAMELINACC' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:327:8: 'mjSENS_FRAMEANGACC' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:330:8: 'mjSENS_SUBTREECOM' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:331:8: 'mjSENS_SUBTREELINVEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:332:8: 'mjSENS_SUBTREEANGMOM' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:335:8: 'mjSENS_USER' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:339:8: 'mjSTAGE_NONE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:340:8: 'mjSTAGE_POS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:341:8: 'mjSTAGE_VEL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:342:8: 'mjSTAGE_ACC' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:346:8: 'mjDATATYPE_REAL' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:347:8: 'mjDATATYPE_POSITIVE' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:348:8: 'mjDATATYPE_AXIS' redeclared
  warning: mujoco_py/generated/../pxd/mjmodel.pxd:349:8: 'mjDATATYPE_QUAT' redeclared
  running build_ext
  building 'mujoco_py.cymj' extension
  creating /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder
  creating /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp
  creating /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud
  creating /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py
  creating /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py
  creating /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/gl
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Imujoco_py -I/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py -I/home/imran/.mujoco/mjpro150/include -I/home/imran/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.c -o /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.o -fopenmp -w
  /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.c:53:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mujoco-py
  Running setup.py clean for mujoco-py
Failed to build mujoco-py
Installing collected packages: mujoco-py
  Running setup.py install for mujoco-py ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-t_1q5w6p/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    Removing old mujoco_py cext /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/cymj_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder_37.so
    running build_ext
    building 'mujoco_py.cymj' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Imujoco_py -I/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py -I/home/imran/.mujoco/mjpro150/include -I/home/imran/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.c -o /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/generated/_pyxbld_1.50.1.68_37_linuxcpuextensionbuilder/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.o -fopenmp -w
    /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/mujoco_py/cymj.c:53:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-t_1q5w6p/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-z3t4vdud/mujoco-py/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the incorrect `Python` headers installed, and the compiler cannot find them.

The failing command has this on the command-line:

```
-I/usr/include/python3.7m
```

And the last line of your issue contains:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u ...
```

You can usually solve this issue by installing the `Python` "development" library. It's unclear which `Linux` you are running, although generally to install the python dev version headers you would do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpython3.7-dev
```

Once installed try using your `pip` command again and it should hopefully work.